# Why are Mealy's number of states less than Moore's number of states in finite state machines?

Tags: state-machines

I was doing an assigment for my digital logic design course.  One of the questions was to design a circuit using Moore's state machine and another one doing the same function using Mealy's state machine.

The function of the circuit was to detect the input of 000 by outputting 1.  The weird thing I noticed about the answer is that Mealy's state machine contains only 3 states while Moore's contains 4 states. I know the difference between them that one of them depends on the input and current state while the other depends on only the current state but I still don't understand why Mealy's machine contain less states.

[image]

[image]

Comment: A knock-on effect of having an output associated with each state for the Moore Machine but having an output associated with a transition for the Mealy machine.

Answer (score 1):

Because you don't need a separate state for the third zero.

If you already had two zeroes coming in, the output "1" can be created by the input only, without changing to a new state. The Moore machine can't do that, it has to transition to an additional state for the third zero in row.